# How to avoid multiple display of a dialog if it is called several times at the same time?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin

This check doesn't work

```
 fun showDialog() {
        if (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FailureDialog.TAG) == null) {
            FailureDialog().show(supportFragmentManager, FailureDialog.TAG)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog is added to the fragment manager asynchronously because of this, the check does not work, in this case it is worth using **showNow()**.

```
fun showDialog() {
        if (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FailureDialog.TAG) == null) {
            FailureDialog().showNow(supportFragmentManager, FailureDialog.TAG)
        }
    }
```